# dynamically representing grouped bar graph data in chartjs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, vuejs2, chart.js

I am currently stuck in dynamically representing the following data in chart js so that it can populate a grouped bar-graph chart.

[image]

the idea is to group by month where each person has accumulated a sum of points over a given month. I am using vuejs and laravel

Comment: Yes, Something like that.

Comment: yes i have, the data is computed from from the server and the above information is the output. its kind of like a multidimensional array.